# Django ModelForm not Saving to Database

Tags: python, django, database, model

I am  new to Django. I am trying to save a form to Database. It doesn't show any error but just won't save it to the DB. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Estate(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    net_area = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    total_area = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    complement = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rooms = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    suits = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    parking_spots = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    logo = models.FileField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('register:create2')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type + ' ' + self.neighborhood
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateView1 (TemplateView):
    template_name = 'register/estate_form1.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form1 = AddForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form1': form1})
    def post(self, request):
        form1 = AddForm(request.POST)
        text = None
        if form1.is_valid():
            text = form1.cleaned_data()
            form1.save()
        args = {'form1': form1, 'text':text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
    model = Estate
    fields = ('type','net_area','total_area','price','cep','state','city','neighborhood','street','number','complement','rooms','suits','parking_spots','bathrooms','description','logo')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if form1.is_valid():
        text = form1.cleaned_data()
        form1.save()
```

Change this to:

```
if form1.is_valid():
         instance = form1.save(commit=False)
         text = form1.cleaned_data()
         instance.save()
```

To save the object, you need to save the instance object, not the form.

Also I see that you have file fields. Files are in `request.FILES` not `request.POST`.

Change `form1 = AddForm(request.POST)` to `form1 = AddForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Comment: This is surely wrong. `ModelForm.save` calls `.save` on the instance if `commit=True`.